# What is the difference between `ARRAY[(value'::text]` and `ARRAY['value']::text[]`

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

This shows up in our `schema.rb` diff sometimes, and I asked my team around and it seems they all have the same postgresql version. With a conditional index, the dumped schema sometimes look like this:

```
t.index ["field_name"], name: "irrelevant", unique: true, 
  where: "((state))::text = ANY (ARRAY[('applied'::character varying)::text]))"
```

and sometimes like that:

```
t.index ["field_name"], name: "irrelevant", unique: true, 
  where: "((state))::text = ANY (ARRAY['applied'::character varying]::text[]))"
```

so the difference seems to be only with the way the casting is expressed:

```
ARRAY['string'::text]
// vs
ARRAY['string']::text[]
```

It seems to me those two castings are equivalent. So my first question is: Are they?

And my second question: where is this discrepancy coming from? As mentioned before all my teammates seem to have the same PGSQL version (though there might be a few missing data points). They definitely have the same rails version, so that can't be the source.

Comment: Hi, for me the result wil be the same but the second is easier to read

Answer (score 0):

The two syntax variants have the same meaning, and PostgreSQL treats them the same. The difference you observe is not caused by a version difference in PostgreSQL, but perhaps in Ruby on Rails.